# Font (Marion font) not displaying inside Font Family in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, custom-font

I included Marion.otf format in XCode.

Its copied and included to target also as showing in this image:

[image: img 1]

Rest other fonts otf format is properly visible & all fonts are included in Build Phases, info.plist too. I also tried to add ttf formats but those are too not visible.

[image]

[image]

Image Depicting Fonts are installed on machine :

[image]

Btw, While trying to print the font family in debugger, I am unable to saw these included fonts there. Used this code to print fonts:

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames
{
    print("\(family)")
    for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
    {
        print("== \(names)")
    }
}
```

Also whenever i tried to open Size Inspector Marion Font is not displayed there. What could be the possible reasons?

[image]

Comment: Have you added it to .plist?

Comment: Yes its added to plist file.

Comment: Have you done _everything_ that https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app says you need to do?

Comment: Up to the point they are assigning to label in Interface Builder I did, But In my app added font is not visible in Attribute Inspector of Interface builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marion font is not supported properly by MacOS High Sierra. As Indicated in this  [doc](http://www.jklstudios.com/misc/osxfonts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add your newly added font in your project .plist also like following key:

```
Fonts provided by application
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Install fonts on your machine.
- Add the fonts in `Info.plist` file.
- Make sure that they’re included in the target

[image]

- Double check that your fonts are included as `Resources` in your bundle

[image]

The font will be available in File Inspector.

> If you are still facing an issue then close xcode and delete derived data and restart xcode again. This trick worked for me.

Comment: I installed fonts on machine. Already added to plist. Deleted derived data , restarted system, Nothing happened.

Comment: print the font family name and see are you using exact same name of the font.

Comment: I am unable to print these custom added fonts in debugger. What could be wrong.

Comment: In first image, It is depicting that Font added to Resource Folder and to target.

Comment: yes, make sure it is added in target and also in copy bundle resources.

Comment: Yes its added there. but still it is not appearing.

Comment: check for the leading and trailing space in font name.

Comment: No there is no Leading and Trailing space in font name.